# JQuery image upload not work for future event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to my user can upload image with post. So with every reply form have a upload form also. User can upload a image by click upload button and then click submit to submit post.

Now my upload form can upload image for first reply, but for 2nd reply upload not work.

My submit process: Ajax append a new reply form with its own dynamic id after submission each reply by php.

So after submit 1st reply I cannot upload any image in 2nd or further reply. But image preview work well here. If I click upload page being refresh.

Here is my upload script: (here 888 is my current id which dynamically set by php)

```js
$(document).on('click', '.uploadReply', function(){
    $("#show_img_upload_rep").slideToggle('slow');
    $('.upfrmrep').show();
});

//Problem is here to upload image
// $(document).on('submit','.upload_Reply',function (e)
$('.upload_Reply').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var EID = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.loading').show();
        $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"../upload.php",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
            success: function(response){
            $('#img'+ EID).attr('value', response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});

//preview image
$(document).on('change','.repfile',function (){
    previewPic(this);
});

function previewPic(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
        $("#preview_rep"+ input.id).attr('src', e.target.result);
        $("#output_rep"+ input.id).show();
        };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

```css
    .replyform {
        top:50px;
     position:relative;
     min-height: 38px;
     width: 100%;
    }
    div.chat {
        width: 90%;
    }

    .replycom {
        font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;
     font-size:12px;
       min-height: 25px;
       color:#000;
       top:0; left:0; z-index:998; background: transparent;
     border: 2px solid #ccc;
     position:relative;
     float:left;
        width:100%;
        margin: 0;
        resize: none;
        padding-right:50px;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    #right {
        position:absolute;
        top: 8px;
        right:0px;
        height: 35px;
        line-height: 35px;
        width: 50px;
        z-index:999;
    }
    #right img {
        cursor:pointer;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width:20px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="replyform">
        <ul>
            <form action="" method="post" class="repfrm888" id="prepfrm">
            <fieldset id="cmntfs">
                <input type="hidden" name="username" id="author" value="'.$_SESSION['username'].'"/>
                <div class="maintbox">
                    <div class="chat">
                    <textarea name="replycom" id="replycom888" class="replycom" placeholder="Type your comment ..."></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div id="right">
                    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fez/512/FEZ-05-128.png" class="uploadReply" id="888"/>
                    </div>
            </form>
                 <div align="left" id="show_img_upload_rep" class="show_img_upload_rep" style="align:left; text-align:left; float:left; margin-top:0px; display:none">
                   
                 <div class="upfrmrep">
     <div id="output_rep888" style="display:none;">
           <img id="preview_rep888" src="" alt="No Image Found"/>
        </div>
        <form class="upload_Reply" id="888'" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <label for="file" style="margin:5px 10px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;float:left;">Filename (Max 200 Kb) :  </label>
           <input type="file" name="file" class="repfile" id="888" value="" style="margin:5px 10px;float:left;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;"/> 
           <input type="submit" class="upload_repimg" id="888" name="upload_btn" value="Upload Picture"/>
        </form>
    </div>
                 </div>
                 </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submitrep" value="" id="repl888" class="replyfrm">Post Reply</button>
        </fieldset>
        </ul>
    </div>
      
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://c0d3.googlecode.com/files/jquery-latest.pack.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to reset the file form:

```
$("form.upload_Reply")[0].reset();
$("form.upload_Reply").trigger("reset");
```

Also, you can get more debugging information from your AJAX call. Try writing error/success data to the console:

```
$('.upload_Reply').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var EID = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.loading').show();
        $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"../upload.php",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(response, statusText, xhr){
            console.log(response);
            console.log(statusText);
            console.log(xhr);
            $('#img'+ EID).attr('value', response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, statusText, errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
            console.log(statusText);
            console.log(xhr);
        },
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Page refresh and cannot get any console log information. `.reset` already applied at post submit. Thank you.