# Upload image immediately on select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here at my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078123/jquery-image-upload-not-work-for-future-event), no one can give me any right solution. So I thank another process to upload image.

Now I want to upload a image immediately after selection by input type file.

How to do it by this script.

html: (here 888 is dynamic id by php)

```
<form class="upload_Reply" id="888'" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename (Max 200 Kb) :</label>
<input type="file" name="file" class="repfile" id="888" value="" /> 
</form>
```

Script:

```
$(document).on('change','.repfile',function (){
    previewPic(this);
});

function previewPic(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("#preview_rep"+ input.id).attr('src', e.target.result);
            $("#output_rep"+ input.id).show();
            var str = e.target.result;
            var ID = input.id;
            UploadFile(str, ID);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
function UploadFile(str, ID) {
     str = ???
     var EID = ID;
     $('.loading').show();
     $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"../upload.php",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(response){
                $('#img'+ EID).attr('value', response);
                $('.loading').hide();
        },
    });
    return false;   
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: No file uploaded. Thank you

Comment: well if no file uploaded there are two reason one you have error in your php other your data is wrong while uploading a file, data error can be solved by using proper data or sending proper data to php.........see my answer :)

Comment: if you have error in your php search for a file upload tutorial in php on google and it will give you proper php code with understanding

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a jquery third party reliable stable plugin rather than your own custom code

with the help of plugin you can

- show progress of file uploaded
- verify if the right file was selected
- preview image
- change preview
- and many more option

> some of the best plugin and easily usable plugin are

- **[uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)** -
- **[blue imp file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)**

> i myself use **[uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)**, it does all the work for me.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
       $('#repfile').uploadify({
         'uploader'  : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
         'script'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
         'cancelImg' : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
         'folder'    : '/uploads',
         'auto'      : true
      });
});
```

Hope my answer is helpful

other than that you can visit here - **[upload files with ajax](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/uploading-files-with-ajax--net-21077)**