# Use jQuery .on for dynamic future event not working for me

Tags: jquery

I have dynamic form for every post reply. I am now using `$('.upload_Reply').on('submit', function(e){` . But as par jQuery documentation for future event I should use any one from below which not work for me:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.upload_repimg',function (e){
//also tried
$("body").delegate('.upload_repimg', 'submit', function(){
```

If I use these, page refreshed without submitting form.

And if I use my current way, reply work only for 1st reply. That means in case of 2 or more reply at a time, reply submit only 1st one, for next try, page refresh.

Where is my problem please.

My form

```
<form class="upload_Reply" method="post" id="up_Rep'.$Sid.'" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" class="repfile" id="'.$Sid.'" value="" /> 
    <input type="submit" class="upload_repimg" id="'.$Sid.'" name="upload_btn" value="Upload Picture"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.upload_Reply` is the form to submit, `.upload_repimg` is the thing to click. I strongly suggest the former: `$(document).on('submit', '.upload_Reply',function (e){`

Comment: Thank you sir, `$(document).on('submit', '.upload_Reply',function (e){` refresh the page not submit.

Comment: Anything in the console?

Comment: Nothing on console, Just refreshing.

Comment: Then I need to see a full example

Comment: If you don`t mind. Please see my previous question where is my detail. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078123/jquery-image-upload-not-work-for-future-event